# PHPUnit test with Zend Framework 3

Tags: php, unit-testing, zend-db, zend-framework3

I got the error below in PHPUnit Controller test in Zend Framework 3:

> Exception 'Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotCreatedException' with message 'Service with name "Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterInterface" could not be created.

The same tests were working fine in Zend Framework 2. The following method in TestController is causing the issue.

```
$this->configureServiceManager($this->getApplicationServiceLocator());
```

is it deprecated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 4 days, I was able to figure out the problem and the fix.

```
 protected function updateConfig($config)
    {
        $config['db'] = [];
```

> ```
>         $config['db']['driver'] = 'Pdo';
> ```

```
        return $config;
    }
```

I had to the driver manually to fix the issue, Hope it will help others with the same error.